# Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Tags: sql-server, php, php-extension

I always used PHP 5.2.3 version, but now I updated PHP to version 5.3.2.

I have problem with MSSQL, I can`t connect to MSSQL server.

I have downloaded a SQL server driver for PHP 1.1

There are a lot of files, I used `php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9`. Put it on *php/ext* directory *`php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9`*.

I have added `extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll` (in php.ini), but it gives an error:

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect() in C:\webserver\www\MSSQl\db_mssql.class.php on line 26

**I have used:**

```
$serverName = "$sql_server";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>$sql_db_name,"UID"=>$sql_user,"PWD"=>$sql_pass);

 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);
 if( $conn === false )
{
     echo "Could not connect.\n";
     die( sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

**Then all work!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open php.ini ,just add this line 
**extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts_vc9.dll**

you need to know  what compiler do you use

```
phpinfo();
```

Compiler  MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
Than Add it.